# Does CGAL support 3D meshing of multiple objects?

Tags: cgal

I would like to mesh multiple (about 25) objects all at once using CGAL.
However, only one or two objects are output.
Is this a bug in CGAL?

I use Gray_level_image to mesh.
The range is from 1.0 to 3.0 and I use float as number type.
Also, 1.0 to 2.0 is set to be in the spatial domain, 2.0 to 3.0 is the object domain, and I set 2.0 as isovalue.

Answer (score 4):

In the upcoming CGAL version, there is a new example in the documentation, documented in the manual at [*3.4.1 Domains From Segmented 3D Images, with a Custom Initialization*](https://cgal.geometryfactory.com/CGAL/doc/master/Mesh_3/index.html#title25). You can find the code in [our Github page](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal). That new example explains how to detect all connected components of the domain coded by the 3D image, and use a custom initialization to ensure that the initial mesh will have vertices on all connected components before the mesh refinement algorithm is launched.

That example is about a 3D segmented image (values at each voxels are integers) whereas you have a 3D gray-level image, but the method would be the same.